# Installed Docker and could not start it up

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I installed docker Windows Desktop 4.26.1 for the first time and its installation was successful. But couldn't start and run.

I tried to install the update using cmd by typing `wsl --update --web-download` command manually but not working. How it can be fixed?